# Jquery toggle('slide') effect is weird

Tags: jquery, html, css

Today, I'm working on my very own website and I try to make a fixed menu on the left.
When I'll click on it, it will display a sub-menu.
Except, the animation is pretty ugly...

I would like my menu-right to seems like it appears from behind menu-left.
My .menu apparition is jerky, I'd like it to be smooth.

*(Then my .content block will move to the right too but I'll do it later.)*

Here is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 /* Submenu - Toggle menu-right */
 $(".menu .menu-left").click(function() {
  $(this).parents().find(".menu-right").toggle('slide');
    $(this).parents().find(".content").toggleClass('padding');
  });
  
});
```

```css
body{margin:0;}
.menu{
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background:antiquewhite;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}

a{display:block;}
.menu-left{
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  width:200px;
  background:bisque;
  float:left;
}
.menu-right{
  position: relative;
  background:burlywood;
  width:200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  margin-left:200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:none;
}
.content{
  background:cadetblue;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding-left:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.content p{margin:0}
.padding{padding-left:400px;}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-left">
    <a>xxx</a>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <a>xxx</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-right">
    <a>xxx</a>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <a>xxx</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
  <p>scroll</p>
</div>
</body>
```